# Can not pass variable to Config::set in laravel elfinder

Tags: laravel, elfinder

I am using laravel 5.5 with backpack as admin panel and i making a project for listing Departments and their Clients and i want to use elfinder to connect to each client folder when i edit the client , So i created a middleware for elfinder to create the client folder and to change the elfinder.dir to that directory the first part of creating dir is done but the problem is in Config::set is not working ,My Code is:

The Middleware :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   $iid = $request->route('client');

    if (!Storage::disk('doc')->exists('$iid')){
    Storage::disk('doc')->makeDirectory($iid);
     }

     \Config::set('elfinder.dir', $iid);

    return $next($request);
}
```

The Route:

```
Route::get('admin/client/{client}/edit', 'Admin\ClientCrudController@edit')->middleware('elfindernew');
```

The ElfinderController :

```
public function showConnector()
{
    $roots = $this->app->config->get('elfinder.roots', []);
    if (empty($roots)) {
        $dirs = (array) $this->app['config']->get('elfinder.dir', []);
        foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
            $roots[] = [
                'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
                'path' => storage_path('doc')."/".$dir,
                'URL' => url($dir), // URL to files (REQUIRED)
                'accessControl' => $this->app->config->get('elfinder.access') // filter callback (OPTIONAL)
            ];
        }
```

I don't Know what is wrong Can someone Help me.....

Comment: service provider name ?

Comment: use Closure;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Storage;

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

> config(['elfinder.dir', $iid]);

Comment: I think that getting the $client from $request is not as string but as array that is not acceptable by the Config command and i tried to set the variable $iid = '1000' for example and pass it to Config and it works.....
So the problem here is how i get the $client from the request not as an array